# why didn't refresh first item of listview and how can I fix it?

Tags: android, listview

I want to hide more than 60 character of textView and show instead `more...` or `see more...`and after clicking on it show `less` in an item of listView adapter with following code  :

```
 if (item.explain.length() > 60) {
            txtExplain.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#15304e'>&larr; " + G.currentActivity.getString(R.string.more) + "</font><br/>" + item.explain.substring(0, 40) + "..."));
            isMoreThan60 = true;
            seeMore = true;
        } else {
            txtExplain.setText(item.explain);
            isMoreThan60 = false;
            seeMore = false;
        }
```

and when I want to set `OnClickListener` I use it in this way :

```
txtExplain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isMoreThan60) {
                    if (seeMore) {
                        txtExplain.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#15304e'>&darr; " + G.currentActivity.getString(R.string.less) + "</font><br/>" + item.explain));
                        seeMore = false;
                    } else {
                        txtExplain.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#15304e'>&larr; " + G.currentActivity.getString(R.string.more) + "</font><br/>" + item.explain.substring(0, 40) + "..."));
                        seeMore = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

**except first Item** I've not any problem  that I should scroll listView until exit first item from screen and use from it's `OnClickListener`

**first item or others that are shown in first time does not REFRESH**

tanks

Comment: Because the view will get recycled. Learn more about adapter view's

Comment: now I just need to find a solution for my present problem ;
can you help me ?

Comment: Your problem is not a problem. It's intended. If you don't want it to behave like that you will have to find a way to do it and from what I've seen you need to start learning how the ArrayAdapter generates it's view's